# Scrollbar not showing - tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have read threads on site to try to resolve this issue but nothing was found that I have not tried where it still does not work.

I am having a little trouble getting the scrollbar to show for my widgets. I have 2 scrollbars that have been written the same way for a Listbox and Text widget in another window and show and function perfectly but in this window the 2 scrollbars written will not display.
I have the code the same as the other functioning scrollbars in the other window but for some reason these 2 are not displaying.

They are placed at ingred and instruc
Some advice would be appreciated.

Code:

```
import os
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
window_3 = tkinter.Toplevel()
window_3.title('Recipes')
window_3.wm_iconbitmap('recipe.ico')
w = 1024
h = 612
ws = window_3.winfo_screenwidth()
hs = window_3.winfo_screenheight()
x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
window_3.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
window_3.title('Recipes')
Recipe_Selection = StringVar()
Dish_Type = StringVar()
Recipe = StringVar()
Cook_Time = StringVar()
Serves = StringVar()
ingred = StringVar()
instruct = StringVar()
dish_type = tkinter.Label(window_3, font=('Times 9 bold'), text='Category:', bg = "#FFD599", fg = '#9A0615')
dish_type.pack()
dish_type.place(x=210, y=125)
dish_type_entry = tkinter.Entry(window_3, textvariable=Dish_Type, width = 29, bg = "#FFD599", fg = '#9A0615', justify=CENTER)
dish_type_entry.place(x=275, y=126) recipe = tkinter.Label(window_3, font=('Times 9 bold'), text='Recipe:', bg = "#FFD599", fg = '#9A0615')
recipe.pack()
recipe.place(x=210, y=145)
recipe_entry = tkinter.Entry(window_3, textvariable=Recipe, width = 29, bg = "#FFD599", fg = '#9A0615', justify=CENTER)
recipe_entry.place(x=275, y=146)
serves = tkinter.Label(window_3, font=('Times 9 bold'), text='Serves:', bg = "#FFD599", fg = '#9A0615')
serves.pack()
serves.place(x=547, y=125)
serves_entry = tkinter.Entry(window_3, textvariable=Serves, width = 3, bg = "#FFD599", fg = '#9A0615', justify=CENTER)
serves_entry.place(x=623, y=126)
cook_time = tkinter.Label(window_3, font=('Times 9 bold'), text='Cook Time:', bg = "#FFD599", fg = '#9A0615')
cook_time.pack()
cook_time.place(x=547, y=145)
cook_time_entry = tkinter.Entry(window_3, textvariable=Cook_Time, width = 11, bg = "#FFD599", fg = '#9A0615', justify=CENTER)
cook_time_entry.place(x=623, y=146)
ingred = tkinter.Text(window_3, font=('Times 9'), height = 20, width=40, bd=1, bg = "#FFD599", fg = '#9A0615')
ingred.pack()
ingred.place(x=210, y=200)
yscroll = tkinter.Scrollbar(command=ingred.yview, orient=tkinter.VERTICAL)
yscroll.place(x=452, y=200)
ingred.configure(yscrollcommand=yscroll.set)
instruct = tkinter.Text(window_3, font=('Times 9'), height = 20, width=40, bd=1, bg = "#FFD599", fg = '#9A0615')
instruct.pack()
instruct.place(x=547, y=200)
yscroll = tkinter.Scrollbar(command=instruct.yview, orient=tkinter.VERTICAL)
yscroll.place(x=789, y=200)
instruct.configure(yscrollcommand=yscroll.set)
dish_type_entry.focus()
saveButton = tkinter.Button(window_3, text='Save Recipe', font='Times 9 bold italic', border = 1, height = 1, width = 14, bg = "#F9F8D6", fg = '#9A0615')##, command = Save)
saveButton.pack
saveButton.place(x=293, y=527)
clear1Button = tkinter.Button(window_3, text='Clear Page', font='Times 9 bold italic', border = 1, height = 1, width = 14, bg = "#F9F8D6", fg = '#9A0615')##, command = clear2)
clear1Button.pack
clear1Button.place(x=630, y=527)
backButton = tkinter.Button(window_3, text='Back', font='Times 9 bold italic', border = 1, height = 1, width = 14, bg = "#F9F8D6", fg = '#9A0615')##, command = close3)
backButton.pack
backButton.place(x=449, y=527)

window_3.mainloop()
```

Comment: This code does not run. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The code presented also has problems with indentation. Please fix that.

Comment: figbeam, I edited the post to show the code, modified, to run. I believe the issue is in the 4th line
    window_3 = tkinter.Toplevel()

Having it as Toplevel is the only way I could get the full code to run through properly, other then the issue with the scrollbars not displaying and an issue moving from window 2 to window 3 (this window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to tell `Scrollbar()` about its master, so it naturally assumes it's root window. Do:

```
yscroll = Scrollbar(window_3, ... etc.
```

By the way, both `ingred` and `instruct` are associated with the same scrollbar: `yscroll` but I gather its just from cutting and pasting code. Also you define `StringVar()` instances with the same name as the text widgets.

Comment: Much appreciate the help... a simple overview and I should have caught it (but didn't). You were correct about the scrollbars being named the same for each widget and that was due to the mod to have it run independently from the rest of the program (oversight on my part). The last 2 StringVar() declared  should not be there and I'm not sure why they are to be honest. I did not realize that they had been put there, they are not needed. Thank you for pointing out the error and my over sight... it is appreciated.